# x-12 ведёт к ошибке TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int'

Tags: python, математика, numpy

Добрый день! Мне необходимо написать программу, которая бы вычисляла функцию |x-12|, в некоторых точках. Проблема в том, что именно с модулем появляются ошибки
Вот мой код:

```
x=[3, 4, 5, 7]
def phi(x):
    return np.absolute(x-12)
y=phi(x)
```

Хотя с другими функциями(np.sin(x) или (x-12)) все работает. Не подскажете в чем проблема? Третий день мучаюсь. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Какие ошибки-то?

Comment: TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-2c12a709bb77> in <module>()
      4 def phi(x):
      5     return np.absolute(x-12)
----> 6 y=phi(x)

<ipython-input-9-2c12a709bb77> in phi(x)
      3 x=[3, 4, 5, 7]
      4 def phi(x):
----> 5     return np.absolute(x-12)
      6 y=phi(x)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int'

Comment: Не очень знаю numpy, но попробуйте обернуть x в np.array: x = np.array([3, 4, 5, 7])

Comment: Спасибо! Сработало!

Comment: Проблема была как раз в `x-12`, т.к. для обычных питоновских списков не переопределен оператор минус...